# Given a class, see if instance has method (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, respond-to

I know in Ruby that I can use `respond_to?` to check if an object has a certain method.

But, given the class, how can I check if the instance has a certain method?

i.e, something like

```
Foo.new.respond_to?(:bar)
```

But I feel like there's gotta be a better way than instantiating a new instance.

Answer (score 395, accepted):

I don't know why everyone is suggesting you should be using `instance_methods` and `include?` when `method_defined?` does the job.

```
class Test
  def hello; end
end

Test.method_defined? :hello #=> true
```

**NOTE**

In case you are coming to Ruby from another OO language OR you think that `method_defined` means ONLY methods that you defined explicitly with:

```
def my_method
end
```

then read this:

In Ruby, a property (attribute) on your model is basically a method also. So `method_defined?` will also return true for properties, ***not just methods.***

For example:

Given an instance of a class that has a String attribute `first_name`:

```
<instance>.first_name.class #=> String

<instance>.class.method_defined?(:first_name) #=> true
```

since `first_name` is both an attribute and a method (and a string of type String).

Comment: method_defined? is the best solution because instance_methods changed between Ruby 1.8 and 1.9. 1.8 returns an array of strings and 1.9 returns an array of symbols. method_defined? takes a symbol in both 1.8 and 1.9.

Comment: Not to mention that :instance_methods will create a new array every call and that :include? will then have to walk the array to tell. In contrast, :method_defined? will internally query the method lookup tables (one hash lookup that is in C) and let you know without creating any new objects.

Comment: While there is at least one advantage when you use it like this, `String.instance_methods(false).include? :freeze`, the **false** argument can tell exactly whether `freeze` method is defined in String class or not. In this case it will return false because `freeze` method is inherited from Kernel module by String, but `String.method_defined? :freeze` will always return true, which can't help much with such a purpose.

Comment: @Bane you're confusing methods on the class with methods available on the instance. `method_defined?` must be used on the class (e.g `Array`), but you are trying to use it on instances (e.g `[]`)

Comment: @banister Absolutely correct.  Thank you for the clarification, it makes perfect sense on reading it.  :)  I've removed my comment so as to not confuse.

Comment: No need to horse around with anything besides `method_defined?`

Comment: And what for private methods? Using [`method_defined?`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Module/method_defined%3F) only public and protected methods are matched. Just use [`private_method_defined?`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Module/private_method_defined%3F)! :)

Answer (score 46):

You can use `method_defined?` as follows:

```
String.method_defined? :upcase # => true
```

Much easier, portable and efficient than the `instance_methods.include?` everyone else seems to be suggesting.

Keep in mind that you won't know if a class responds dynamically to some calls with `method_missing`, for example by redefining `respond_to?`, or since Ruby 1.9.2 by defining [`respond_to_missing?`](http://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/vm_method.c#L1288).

Comment: Note that if you've got an instance in hand and you don't know it's class, you can do `instance.class.method_defined? :upcase`

Answer (score 29):

Actually this doesn't work for both Objects and Classes.

This does:

```
class TestClass
  def methodName
  end
end
```

So with the given answer, this works:

```
TestClass.method_defined? :methodName # => TRUE
```

But this does NOT work:

```
t = TestClass.new
t.method_defined? : methodName  # => ERROR!
```

So I use this for both classes and objects:

Classes:

```
TestClass.methods.include? 'methodName'  # => TRUE
```

Objects:

```
t = TestClass.new
t.methods.include? 'methodName'  # => TRUE
```

Comment: For instances you can also use `instance.class.method_defined?'

Comment: It depends on your version of ruby.  This method above works for all versions including 1.8.7.

Comment: @Luksurious: I don't think that will work if you have mixins.

Answer (score 10):

The answer to "[Given a class, see if instance has method (Ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303347/given-a-class-see-if-instance-has-method-ruby/3304680#3304680)" is better. Apparently Ruby has this built-in, and I somehow missed it. My answer is left for reference, regardless.

Ruby classes respond to the methods [`instance_methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods) and [`public_instance_methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-public_instance_methods). In Ruby 1.8, the first lists all instance method names in an array of strings, and the second restricts it to public methods. The second behavior is what you'd most likely want, since `respond_to?` restricts itself to public methods by default, as well.

```
Foo.public_instance_methods.include?('bar')
```

In Ruby 1.9, though, those methods return arrays of symbols.

```
Foo.public_instance_methods.include?(:bar)
```

If you're planning on doing this often, you might want to extend `Module` to include a shortcut method. (It may seem odd to assign this to `Module` instead of `Class`, but since that's where the `instance_methods` methods live, it's best to keep in line with that pattern.)

```
class Module
  def instance_respond_to?(method_name)
    public_instance_methods.include?(method_name)
  end
end
```

If you want to support both Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9, that would be a convenient place to add the logic to search for both strings and symbols, as well.

Comment: `method_defined?` is better :)

Comment: @banister - oh, my, and I somehow missed it! xD Threw a +1 behind @Marc's answer, and added a link to make sure it isn't missed :)

Answer (score 5):

Try `Foo.instance_methods.include? :bar`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the best way, but you could always do this:

```
Foo.instance_methods.include? 'bar'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're checking to see if an object can respond to a series of methods, you could do something like:

```
methods = [:valid?, :chase, :test]

def has_methods?(something, methods)
  methods & something.methods == methods
end
```

the `methods & something.methods` will join the two arrays on their common/matching elements. something.methods includes all of the methods you're checking for, it'll equal methods. For example:

```
[1,2] & [1,2,3,4,5]
==> [1,2]
```

so

```
[1,2] & [1,2,3,4,5] == [1,2]
==> true
```

In this situation, you'd want to use symbols, because when you call .methods, it returns an array of symbols and if you used `["my", "methods"]`, it'd return false.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is something wrong with `method_defined?` in Rails. It may be inconsistent or something, so if you use Rails, it's better to use something from [`attribute_method?(attribute)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute_method-3F).

"[testing for method_defined? on ActiveRecord classes doesn't work until an instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013773/testing-for-method-defined-on-activerecord-classes-doesnt-work-until-an-instan)" is a question about the inconsistency.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Foo
 def self.fclass_method
 end
 def finstance_method
 end
end

foo_obj = Foo.new
foo_obj.class.methods(false)
=> [:fclass_method] 

foo_obj.class.instance_methods(false)
=> [:fclass_method]
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 2):

`klass.instance_methods.include :method_name` or `"method_name"`, depending on the Ruby version I think.

Answer (score 2):

While `respond_to?` will return true only for public methods, checking for "method definition" on a class may also pertain to private methods.

On Ruby v2.0+ checking both public and private sets can be achieved with

```
Foo.private_instance_methods.include?(:bar) || Foo.instance_methods.include?(:bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

On my case working with ruby 2.5.3 the following sentences have worked perfectly :

```
value = "hello world"

value.methods.include? :upcase
```

It will return a boolean value true or false.