# testing for method_defined? on ActiveRecord classes doesn't work until an instantiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I'm having a problem testing for methods that correspond to the database columns of an ActiveRecord. Take any model you've got (in my case Document), and do the following:

```
$  rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.9)
>> Document.method_defined?(:id)
=> false
>> Document.new
=> #<Document id: nil, feed_id: nil >
>> Document.method_defined?(:id)
=> true
```

There is obviously some ActiveRecord lifecycle work going on as a prerequisite to .new() that's adding all the database columns as methods to the class.

Where this really complicates things is during unit testing. I'd like have a class that in runtime accepts ActiveRecord classes and does some validation on them

For example

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def work1
    # something
  end
end
class Command
  def operates_on(clazz, method)
    # unless I add a "clazz.new" first, method_defined? will fail 
    # on things like :id and :created_at
    raise "not a good class #{clazz.name}" if ! clazz.method_defined?(method)
    # <logic here>
  end
end

describe Command do
  it "should pass if given a good class" do
    Command.new.operates_on(Foo,:work1)
  end
  it "should pass if given a database column" do
    # this FAILS
    Command.new.operates_on(Foo,:id)
  end
  it "should raise if given an invalid class/method combo" do
    lambda { Command.new.operates_on(Foo,:non_work) }.should raise_error
  end
end
```

What can I do to assert (other than making a junk instance with .new()) that the ActiveRecord has done its initialization?

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be a bug but isn't likely going to be fixed soon.

[Inconsistent method_defined? behaviour](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4317-inconsistent-method_defined-bevahiour)

I found that .attribute_method? works on the class to do what you need.  You can find more information at [ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! `.attribute_method?` solves the problem!