# Checking for an instance method

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

Is there a class method to check if there is a certain instance method for that class? Something like `respond_to?` that is a class method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use

```
 method_defined?
```

,which is class method to check whether particular class has instance method defined or not. 
Following link will explain you more

[Given a class, see if instance has method (Ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303347/given-a-class-see-if-instance-has-method-ruby)

Comment: +1, I thought that was for the instance (class instance in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Use method_defined? on Class

Ex: Array.method_defined? :sort