# How to find controller methods defined in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to find controller methods defined for a controller in Rails 4? I look around in `Rails.application` and find named routes defined but not the methods defined.

Comment: Maybe in the `controllers` folder where the controllers are defined? Or are you asking about `ActionController::Base`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to list all methods defined inside a specific controller (ie. `UsersController`):

```
>> UsersController.instance_methods(false)
=> [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :update_remote, :user_params]
```

If you just want `public` methods:

```
>> UsersController.public_instance_methods(false)
=> [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :update_remote]
```

If you need the whole list of methods, also the ones from ancestors, call those methods with `true` (or without param, since it's the default):

- `UsersController.instance_methods`
- `UsersController.public_instance_methods`

More docs here: http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods

**instance_methods**

> Returns an array containing the names of the public and protected instance methods in the receiver. For a module, these are the public and protected methods; for a class, they are the instance (not singleton) methods. If the optional parameter is false, the methods of any ancestors are not included.

**public_instance_methods**

> Returns a list of the public instance methods defined. If the optional parameter is false, the methods of any ancestors are not included.

---

Alternatively, if you need to get the "local" methods, including the ones included from other modules, you can achieve it by:

```
u = UsersController.new
u.methods - u.class.superclass.instance_methods
```

Comment: The public_instance_methods lists out only the methods defined by the controller and does not include the methods included from other module.

Comment: @user938363 I just updated answer with an alternative approach to list all methods (also the ones included by another module).

Answer (score 1):

`TestClass.instance_methods(false)`

to get only instance methods that belong to that class only.

Answer (score 0):

`method_defined?` seems to be straightforward to find out if a method is defined for a class. For example, `QuotesController.method_defined?(:index)` returns true if there is index action in controller.

For an instance, it is `obj_instance.methods.include?(:method_name)`

Here is a post about method_defined? and methods.include?:
[Given a class, see if instance has method (Ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303347/given-a-class-see-if-instance-has-method-ruby).

Comment: Yes, but this is not an answer to your OP, originally you asked for: "How to find controller methods defined for a controller in Rails 4?" So to find the methods you have to use `QuotesController.instance_methods(false)`. `method_defined?` is used to check for an existing method.